# What is this calligraphic letter?

Tags: math-fonts

[image]

This is in *Principles of Algebraic Geometry 1994* by Griffiths and Harris (bottom of page 139).

Comment: It Is the calligraphic letter A of Mtpro2 package.

Comment: @Sebastiano https://ctan.org/pkg/Mtpro2 returns 404 to me.

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite

Comment: @Niranjan The correct link is: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite